# jQuery prepend <i> to table row first child

Tags: jquery, html

I am having an odd issue, I have several dozen paged with table data that I need to append a font-awesome icon to. Instead of editing every page and having to remember to do it later, I'd rather use jQuery to do it for me. Right now, this is what I have:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('tr.expand').each(function(){
        $(tr.expand td:first:child).prepend("<i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>");
    });
});
```

This works to add the  to the first td of each row, but it's adding the  20 times to the  element! What am I missing here?

Comment: If there are 20 rows of `tr.expand` the outer object `$('tr.expand')` will hold 20 elements and therefore `.each()` will be executed that many times.

Inside of the .each()-function you create another object with `tr.expand` which will again hold 20 elements and even without `.each()` the .prepend()-function will be executed on each element.
So you are executing it 20*20 times resulting in 20 icons in all of your 20 rows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to use `each()`. Try like following.

```
$('tr.expand td:first-child').prepend('<i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>');
```

Comment: actually, yours loads faster, wish I could mark both

Answer (score 0):

Use `this` object.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('tr.expand').each(function(){
        $(this).find('td').first().prepend("<i class=\"fa fa-angle-down\"></i>");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the this selector witch will only select that one 'TR' and then use the .first() on the 'TD" to add an another 'I' element to it like this. You don't have to use the each function:

```
$("tr.expand").first().prepend("<i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>");
```

This will make it where only this 'TR' with the class expand will have its first 'TD' filed with one 'I' element. This would be the simple way of doing it